# How can I use Java to implement SSE(Server-Sent Event) server side without returning SseEmitter?

Tags: spring-boot, openai-api, server-sent-events, api-gateway, large-language-model

I am using the Java Raptor (Internal framework, made some modifications on *Spring Boot*) framework to implement the server side of **SSE**.
However, my API is restricted, which means that my requests and response bodies must be custom.

I have seen many examples of SSE Java servers that require returning SseEmitter. How can I return a custom structure without returning SseEmitter? How do I send the data if using a custom structure?

I really need an example that can return a custom response body and send data normally.

I tried returning SseEmitter, and it ran well until returning, but the last step caused an error in returning due to API limitations. It is a POST method.

I've also tried returning an existing structure (non-SseEmitter), but Send doesn't seem to succeed. Although I have used `sseEmitter.send` in my code.

```
// Controller interface
@Path("/predict-model-stream")
public interface PredictModelStream {

    /**
     * Predict model stream
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS})
    Response predictModelStream(
            final @HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType,

            final @Valid @NotNull(message = "MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER")
            PredictRequest body
    );
}

// Response Body must be a custom class
```

In fact, I'm implementing a ChatGPT Gateway SSE functionality. The Gateway service receives front-end requests and forwards them to the downstream model service. The downstream model service can already correctly use SSE to return results, while the Gateway service can only return custom structures due to limitations. This means that I cannot use the specialized structure SseEmitter provided in Spring. Any suggestions?